# Can we build the microservice Rest APIs using Node JS and express framework?

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, node-modules

I would like to build an e-commerce application using node js with an express library  as a backend and React as a frontend.

If we can able to build the microservice rest APIs using node js and express library then could you please guide or give me some inputs like what are open source libraries we can use?

Comment: You can build any microservice with any architecture you prefer, for inter-services communication, Kafka, RabbitMQ, or my personal fav, GRPC among others can be used, you can even use Rest API(not the best but gets the job done), your question is quite wide can you narrow down to what exactly you need?

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/building-microservices-node-js/#:~:text=Using%20a%20microservice%20offers%20flexibility,scalable%2C%20and%20easy%20to%20maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I would like to build a medium scale e-commerce application, and in that project, multiple microservices may be needed for better performance like search admin, user management, functionality, notification, etc. if I use the java then the project budget will be more then what we estimated. So I am trying to build it using node js and express framework.